# moving a jquery dialog button to the left

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to get one of the buttons in my group of jquery dialog buttons to display on the left.  But I think this is impossible because jquery wraps the button group in a .  I've tried adding float:left dynamically, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <!--this should be on the left-->
    <button id="lbCreateGroup" class="createButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <!--these 2 buttons should be on the right-->
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with just css...

```
#lbCreateGroup { float: left; }
.ui-button { float: right; }
```

Here's a working fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/tEKWJ/

By default, all the elements with `.ui-button` class will float to the right, so you may want to add another class specifically for this.  The css for an element that is specified by its id will always override that which is specified by class, so you use the id of the one you want to float left.

Incidentally, jQueryUI may well float the buttons right by default anyway, so you may not need the 2nd line of css :)

Comment: Is there any chance of a link to the page, or a fiddle that shows your problem?  I having trouble reproducing your issue.